# Sending simple text commands to a ROS node from an external program written in Java

Tags: control, ros, java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've never used ROS before and therefore probably don't know the correct terminology for what I'm asking; I therefore apologise in advance if this has already been answered and I didn't know how to search for it.

This group have created a ROS framework for the Parrot Ar.Drone quadrocopter: [can't post the link but it's the tum_ardrone project, it's on the ROS website] that allows waypoint based navigation using visual processing algorithms. This would be extremely useful for me in my research into UAV control schemes and I have an AR.Drone available.

Commands can apparently be sent to the drone through simple text commands like "goto [doube x] [double y] [double z] [double yaw]" which are sent to a control node. What I would like to do is have an external (preferably) java program interact with ROS to pass the commands to the quadrocopter and then receive the video stream back.

Is this possible, and if so where might I find some information as to how to implement it?

Many thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51902/sending-simple-text-commands-to-a-ros-node-from-an-external-program-written-in-java/) by [MetalBuds](https://answers.ros.org/users/3934/metalbuds/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just look for [rosjava](http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/). Sending simple strings is one of the first tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1